# UIButton setTitleColor is not working when i set the button state to disable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, swift4

In my app, I want to disable one button so I wrote code like this

```
plusBtn.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .disabled)
```

I wrote this code inside `viewDidLoad()` method. In storyboard, the default button color is green but for the first time when view Load it will in disable mode with gray color(I know `isEnabled` property is there to handle this but I want to do like this) and one more important thing when I change the button state to `.normal` its working fine, But for `.disable` it's not working why?

Answer (score 0):

with this code you do not disable the button. you just set the color for disabled button.

but if you did set the property enabled to false in storyboard and did correctly connect your button to your code, it works. i just tested it. See image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Write it in `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad()`

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        plusBtn.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .disabled)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not completely understand where do you set your buttons state to disabled but make sure you do it after you set disabled state's title color to gray.

You can try adding break points to both lines and see which one is executed first.